# Merging multiple AIFF files from the command line

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to put multiple commands in different voices into the same audio file. I know you can do this:

```
say -v "Cellos" "la di da" -o ex.aiff
```

But I have multiple commands in different voices such as:

```
say -v "Cellos" "la di da"
say -v "Bells" "di da da"
```

Is there a way to  have `say` put multiple phrases using different settings in to the same aiff or mp3 file? (If not, can I merge the individual files programmatically using terminal tools and commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). Create a file named `input.txt` with the contents (one line for each file):

```
file 'ex.aiff'
file 'ex2.aiff'
```

Then run `ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.aiff`.

Comment: I found that quotes were not accepted in `input.txt`, instead, spaces had to be escaped with a backslash. Also, I had to add `-safe 0` to the options of `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sox`:

```
sox 1.aif 2.aif output.aif
```

Using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(printf %s\\n "file '$PWD/"{1,2}.aif\') -c copy output.aif
```

Comment: The `printf` looks very very wrong. I'm guessing you want `<(printf "file '%s'\n" {1,2}.aif)`

Comment: Neither given ffmpeg solution works, both just give errors. "Unsafe filename" and "String required" respectively.